# Strange bug in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax

I make an AJAX post to the server. One variable may or may be not present in this post. I call this variable readOnly. And if it is present, it may take values 1, "true", 0, "false". On the server side I check this variable like so:

```
if (isset($_POST['readOnly']) && ($_POST['readOnly'] == 1 || $_POST['readOnly'] == 'true')) {
    $readOnly_ = 1;
} else {
    $readOnly_ = 0;
}
file_put_contents("readOnly.txt", $readOnly_ . "->" . ($readOnly_=='true'));
```

So, when this variable in not present in the AJAX call, `$readOnly_` variable should take `0` value and when I check this situation, I get this line in readOnly.txt file:

```
0->1
```

So, how one, and the same variable may have value 0 and true at the same Time? In other words, if `$readOnly_` is 0, why it is also true? What the heck is going on?

Comment: Consider using the strict identical operator `===`

Comment: I wonder why deceze believes, that it is a duplicate? Can you provide any explanation? Do you think, that 0 integer is converted to "true" string?

Comment: I would possible agree with this, if 0 converted to false. But what I have is absolutely irrational. IMHO

Comment: There's a nice explanation of [comparing values of different data types here in the PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).... but simplified, comparing number `0` with string `true` will evaluate to boolean `true` because string `true` will be cast to integer `0` for the comparison, and `0 == 0` is true

Comment: try this $readOnly_ = $_POST['readOnly']; file_put_contents("readOnly.txt", $readOnly_ . "->" .$readOnly);

Comment: @Casper, there is no `$readOnly` variable in my code. so, it prints just 0->

Comment: the string `true` gets casted to an integer, which is `0`

Comment: Thank you, guys! What a strange conversion!

Comment: Yes, it's one of PHP's big pitfalls. You should either learn the conversion tables by heart, or stick to `===` comparisons.